# Is it possible to get the email account of a Github user on social signin with Django-Allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I set up [Allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to the point where I am able to sign in via Github.

According to the docs Allauth should be able to ask for a Github email address if the following setting is included:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

(`SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` by default)

However, **including this setting does not ask for an email address!**

Might it have something to do with setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS`? (If so, can someone provide an example of that setting?)